# I can't access labels via "for" attribute in Firefox, but can in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-closure

I have a form which I need to dynamically populate the labels of (which was generated with Google Closure).  I got it working in chrome, but when I tried it in Firefox it wouldn't work, and fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: this.document.getElementById(...)[$i].labels is undefined
....document.getElementById('dialog-form')[$i].labels[0].innerHTML = "$" + varNewPr...
```

Examining through the Firebug console I get the following error:

```
>>> this.document.getElementById('dialog-form')[4]
<input id="price1" type="radio" value="1" percentage="90" adoptname="90" name="price">
>>> this.document.getElementById('dialog-form')[4].labels
undefined
```

However using the native debugging console in chrome it works  (the different values for value= and adoptname= are due to dynamically reusing the form)

```
>this.document.getElementById('dialog-form')[4]
<input type=​"radio" name=​"price" adoptname=​"180" id=​"price1" percentage=​"90" value=​"2">​
>this.document.getElementById('dialog-form')[4].labels
[<label class=​"adopt-label" for=​"price1">​$0​</label>​]
```

Here is the html form code after it came out of the Google Closure compiler:

```
// This file was automatically generated from basic.soy.
// Please don't edit this file by hand.

if (typeof examples == 'undefined') { var examples = {}; }
if (typeof examples.simple == 'undefined') { examples.simple = {}; }


examples.simple.adoptForm = function(opt_data, opt_ignored) {
return '<div class="adopt-general">
<div class="adopt-header">

....

<ul class="adopt-list">
<li><label>Tell me if the price drops below:</label>
<li><input type="radio" name="price" adoptname="$' + soy.$$escapeHtml(Math.round(opt_data.price * 0.9)) + '" id="price1" percentage="90" value="' + soy.$$escapeHtml(opt_data.itemNumber) + '" />
<label class="adopt-label" for="price1">$' + soy.$$escapeHtml(Math.round(opt_data.price * 0.9)) + '</label>
<input type="radio" name="price" adoptname="$' + soy.$$escapeHtml(Math.round(opt_data.price * 0.8)) + '" id="price2" percentage="80" value="' + soy.$$escapeHtml(opt_data.itemNumber) + '" />
<label class="adopt-label" for="price2">$' + soy.$$escapeHtml(Math.round(opt_data.price * 0.8)) + '</label>
<input type="radio" name="price" adoptname="$' + soy.$$escapeHtml(Math.round(opt_data.price * 0.7)) + '" id="price3" percentage="70" value="' + soy.$$escapeHtml(opt_data.itemNumber) + '" />
<label class="adopt-label" for="price3">$' + soy.$$escapeHtml(Math.round(opt_data.price * 0.7)) + '</label></ul>

    ...;

};
```

The javascript code is here:

```
for(var $i = 0; $i < $myDialogLength; $i++){
    this.document.getElementById('dialog-form')[$i].setAttribute("value",skuNumber);
    this.document.getElementById('dialog-form')[$i].checked = false;
    if(this.document.getElementById('dialog-form')[$i].getAttribute("percentage") !== null){
        varIdNum = this.document.getElementById("dialog-form")[$i].getAttribute("percentage");
        var varNewPrice = (varIdNum*price/100);
        this.document.getElementById('dialog-form')[$i].setAttribute("adoptname",varNewPrice);            
        this.document.getElementById('dialog-form')[$i].labels[0].innerHTML = "$" + varNewPrice;
    }
....
}
```

The last line in the code is throwing the error in Firefox.  I am using JQuery also and do not have much javascript experience so I apologize for the non-optimal code.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that means Firefox doesn't support the `.labels` property.

Try this instead:

```
document.querySelector("[for='"+ID+"']").innerHTML = "$"+varNewPrice;
```

Just make sure that `ID` is some reference to the ID of your element. Your current code is really weird... it almost looks like you have multiple elements with the same ID...

Comment: If the element returned is a form, then the controls are available by index, so `getElementById('formId')[0]` will reference the first control in the form (if there is one). *cf.* `form.elements[0]`.

Comment: @RobG The function `getElementById` implies one. Get *element*, not element *s*

Comment: Yes, in this case it returns a form element, so then `form[n]` will return the nth control in the form (in this case an input element) or *undefined* if there isn't one. It's not nice code, but it "works". Also not sure if the OP wants to replace the entire content of the label, or just the text (since the input element may be a child or sibling of the label).

Comment: Ooh, I get it now. Okay. Yeah, that's nasty XD

Comment: Thanks so much, that replacement made it work in Firefox and IE.  I was just trying to change the text of the label.  I will check again, but I thought I avoided multiple elements for the same ID.  As for the code non-optimal is an understatement, not nice and nasty are better descriptors.  Thankfully it will get refactored and reviewed.  Thanks again, I appreciate the help!

Comment: If you just want to replace the label text, be very careful using *innerHTML* since in many cases the label contains the element it is the label for and replacing the innerHTML will remove the element. You're probably better off to put the value in a span and use a similar scheme to reference the span rather than the label, e.g. `...getElementById(inputID + 'Value')`.

Comment: @RobG thanks good point to take into account.  It doesn't seem to effect this example, but these two lines worked the same `<span class="adopt-label" for="price1">${round($price * 0.9)}</span>
        <label class="adopt-label" for="price1">${round($price * 0.9)}</label>` so I used span.  Don't know how to add a plus to your comment, but it might be because I have too few points.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that:

```
this.document.getElementById('dialog-form')[4]
```

is a reference to an input with `id="price1" ... name="price"`. You could also get this same element using:

```
this.document.forms['dialog-form'].price
```

But anyway, the interface for [HTMLInputElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025) doesn't included a *labels* property. What do you expect it to do, return the associated label (if there is one)?

You need to say what you are trying to do and post a relevant part of the DOM, preferably as HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your input RobG, yes I wanted it to return the label associated with it via the for= attribute of the label.  In chrome this seemed to work, but I guess it is not standard.  Also the problem with getting the element via the name property is that it is a group of radio buttons so three buttons have the same name.  Thanks again for your time, next time I will be more clear on what I am trying to do.